# Zip() function: variable being a list of lists

Tags: python

So I'm having difficulty with the zip() function:

With a simple example:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
c = [a, b]
```

`zip(a, b)` is the same as  `zip(c[0], c[1])`

But imagine that c has a lot more of lists as elements, and not a fixed number of elements, instead of doing:
`zip(c[0], c[1], ..., c[-2], c[-1])`

I tried:
`zip(c[:])`

But it's clearly not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use

```
zip(*c)
```

Instead